# How to set DataGridComboBoxColumn font properties?

Tags: wpf

what is the easy way (not using a DataGridTemplateColumn) to change the font properties (at least family and size) of a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works nicely to make everything unreadable:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ...>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Wingdings"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Wingdings"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

The principle should be apparent.

(*Note: Setting `TextElement.FontFamily` directly in the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` declaration does not work.*)